# Access other field of currently logged user In domain in Action window Odoo13

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-13

I have a domain in window action. I want to filter the data by this domain, and I need to acccees another field of currently logged user some like this (`uid.branch_ids.ids`) and use this field in the domain. I don't know how to do it Here is my code:

```
<field name="domain">[('type', '=', 'out_invoice'),('invoice_line_ids.branch_id', 'in', uid.branch_ids.ids)]</field>
```

when I run this code gives me this error:

> object has no attribute 'branch_ids'

But I have the `branch_ids` in my `res.users` model

Comment: Try to bring your `uid.branch_ids.ids` as a hidden field to your view. If I remember right, you need to have a field in your view if you refer to it.

Comment: `uid` is just an integer. You could try to use `user` instead, but i'm not sure if it will work in odoo 13 or odoo in general.

Comment: The user will not work here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The window action domain is evaluated with the following context:

```js
allowed_company_ids: Array [ 1 ]
context_today: function context_today()​
current_date: Object { __is_type: false, _value: "2022-08-22" }
datetime: Object { __is_type: false, timedelta: {…}, datetime: {…}, … }
default_type: "out_invoice"
lang: "en_US"
relativedelta: Object {__init__: __init__(), __name__: "relativedelta", __is_type: true, … }
time: Object { __is_type: false, strftime: {…} }
tz: "Europe/London"
tz_offset: function tz_offset()
uid: 2
```

As you can see, the user record is not available.

***Edit:***

You can't use the field traversal to reach a user id from the branch record. Unfortunately you can't have a user record in the evaluation context because an object of type `res.users` can't be JSON serializable.

The window action domain is used to filter data in the search function, so you can override the search function and customize your domain there.

***Example:***

```
class AccountInvoice(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'account.move'

    @api.model
    def search_read(self, domain=None, fields=None, offset=0, limit=None, order=None):
        domain = domain or []
        if self.env.context.get('default_type') == 'out_invoice':
            domain.append(['invoice_line_ids.branch_id', 'in', self.env.user.branch_ids.ids])
        return super(AccountInvoice, self).search_read(domain, fields, offset, limit, order)
```

Comment: I don't want to compare based on the user id, I want to compare by the branch id which is located in both models. I need to use the user id to reach branch_ids related to this user.

Comment: You can only use the user id as an integer

Comment: A brach belongs to a user if the inverse field value is equal to the user id.

Comment: The user has more than one branch, The branch_ids in the user model is Many2many field.

Comment: I have a user that can belong to multiple branches. When I create an invoice it belongs to a specific branch. I want when the user login in and goes to the Invoices menu, they should see only the invoices that are in the list of branches they belong. I have tried the global record rule but it doesn't work. this the scenario

Comment: Please provide the fields definition (In Invoice & User models)

Comment: in the user model   :  branch_ids = fields.Many2many('sfpa.branch', string='Branches')

Comment: in the invoice model :     branch_id = fields.Many2one('sfpa.branch', string='Branch')

Comment: You can override directly the search domain instead of the action domain. I will remove my example, as it is obsolete.

Comment: You made my day man, big love